# Excluding certain routes in Django with React Router?

Tags: python, django, reactjs, react-router

I am currently building a React with a Django REST backend. I have come into this one little problem I can't get past that has to do with Routing.

Here is my `urls.py` file.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^djangojs/', include('djangojs.urls')),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='exampleapp/itworks.html')),
    url(r'^(?:.*)/?$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='exampleapp/itworks.html')),
]
```

Using this, it lets the react router do it's thing on the front end. For example, if I wanted to go to `127.0.0.1:8000/mentors` then it will take me to the page I have set for React Router.

However, doing API calls in the frontend also returns the react page rather than the API endpoint because of this. So whenever I remove the last line in the code above: `url(r'^(?:.*)/?$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='exampleapp/itworks.html')),`, then it gets the API returned in JSON format successfully. Problem is now when I try to go to the links it will return the Django 404 page rather than the React page I set in the React Router.

Is there anyway I can get the best of both worlds?

Comment: How are you calling the api exactly?

Comment: I am using Axios on the front end. @BurhanKhalid

Comment: Sorry, I meant the URL you are using,

Comment: I am using the localhost URL that Django has made for me. To query mentors for example: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/mentors @BurhanKhalid

Comment: Are you saying when you type `127.0.0.1:8000/api/mentors`, you are getting the api response, and additional content?

Comment: Sorry if I am not clear. When I type that in I get a blank page and the console will say that it's not a route that I made in React Router. @BurhanKhalid

Comment: When you enter `127.0.0.1:8000/api/mentors` on browser, it will hit Django backend if you config ` url(r'^api/', include(router.urls))` correctly. Can you show `mentors` route in `url(r'^api/', include(router.urls))`?